# Poetry missing as interpreter option in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, python-poetry

I have Poetry installed on both a Mac and a Windows computer and have been using it without issue on both. However, PyCharm on both machines fails to list poetry as an interpreter option. What do I need to do to get poetry to show up in PyCharm? It's officially supported now so I guess I'm missing something?

[Jetbrains official documentation on Poetry on PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html)

Windows Example
[image]

OSX Example
[image]

Comment: What version of PyCharm do you use? Poetry integration is available from 2021.3 on. Versions before need the Plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14307-poetry

Comment: That was it. I didn't realize PyCharm's update only handles patches not larger changes. If you'd like to officially answer this, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poetry integration is available in PyCharm from 2021.3 on.
Versions before need the Plugin http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14307-poetry